# Rails Nested forms, not add a second element if user dont clic on "add new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Hi im using Rails Nested forms, i need something very simple, but i cant figure put why, cause im a noob in Rails.

In the nested  forms, when the user select an option on the list, the script automatically insert a second select list, in blank, this blanks remains always there,

Is there a way to avoid this.. so if you select nothing happends, (just the selection ofcourse) until you hit "add new", just then the script add a new select list for user to add another option.

Thanks..

View code

```
<%= f.fields_for :citizens do |citizen_form| %>

    <div>
      <%= citizen_form.label  :citizen, t('generales.citizen')  %>
      <%= citizen_form.select :country_id , Country.all.collect {|p| [ t("generales."+p.iso), p.id ] }, { :include_blank => true } , { :class => 'pca33' } %>
      <div id="delerr"><%= citizen_form.link_to_remove t('generales.delete') %></div>
    </div>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add t('generales.add'), :citizens %>
```

Model Player.rb

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :clubs
  has_many   :links
  has_many   :references
  has_many   :achievements
  has_many   :citizens
  has_and_belongs_to_many :languages
  has_and_belongs_to_many :selections

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :clubs,        :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :links,        :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['url'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :references,   :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :achievements, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :citizens,     :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['country_id'].blank?}

  attr_accessible :name,
    :lastname,
    :birthday,
    :height,
    :height_measure,
    :weight,
    :weight_measure,
    :inches,
    :city,
    :birthplace,
    :other_languages,
    :cp,
    :phone,
    :cellphone,
    :web_page,
    :game_status,
    :club,
    :actual_club,
    :actual_country_club,
    :actual_division_club,
    :actual_contract_expiration_club,
    :last_club,
    :last_country_club,
    :last_division_club,
    :last_contract_expiration_club,
    :position,
    :alternative_position,
    :dominant_leg,

    #normal player
    :short_passes,
    :long_passes,
    :shots_half_distance,
    :shots_long_distance,
    :ball_habilities,
    :offensive_capability,
    :ball_driving,
    :defense_capability,
    :dribbling,
    :velocity,
    :vision_field,
    :movements_wothout_ball,
    :recovery_ball,
    :head_ball,
    :lidership,
    :teamwork,

    #goalkeeper
    :air_game,
    :clearance_technique, #técnica de despeje
    :ball_keep, #atajes
    :flexibility, #flexibilidad
    :penalty_keep, #atajar penales
    :achique,
    :defense_communication,
    :foot_game,
    :velocity_reaction, #reflejos
    :area_domination,
    :goalkeep_teamwork,
    :goalkeep_lidership,

    :strenghts,
    :weaknesses,

    :aditional_information,

    :active,

    :clubs_attributes,
    :links_attributes,
    :references_attributes,
    :achievements_attributes,
    :citizens_attributes,
    :avatar_file_name,
    :avatar_content_type,
    :avatar_file_size,
    :avatar,

    :language_ids,
    :selection_ids


    POSITIONS = %w{
      goalkeeper
      defense
      medium
      offensive
    }

    LEG = %w{
      left
      right
      both
    }

    # altura
    HEIGHT = (1..200).to_a

    INCH = (1..11).to_a

    # peso
    WEIGHT = (1..300).to_a

    HEIGHT_MEASURE = %w{
      cms
      pies
    }

    WEIGHT_MEASURE = %w{
      kgs
      lbs
    }


    Paperclip.interpolates :random_hex do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.random_hex
    end

    has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :profile => "300x300", :thumb => "100x100#"},
    :url  => "/assets/people/:id/:style/:hash.:extension",
    :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/people/:id/:style/:hash.:extension",
    :hash_secret => "longSecretString"

    validates_attachment_size         :avatar, :less_than    => 2.megabytes # Solo aceptar imágenes menores a 2 Mb.
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/x-png', 'image/gif']

    def defeated?
      t = Time.now - created_at

      mm, ss = t.divmod(60)
      hh, mm = mm.divmod(60)
      dd, hh = hh.divmod(24)

      dd > 180 ? true : false
    end
end
```

Model citizen.rb

```
class Citizen < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :country_id

  belongs_to :player


end
```

Comment: Sounds like you have some JS going on that is adding the new fields whenever the selection changes. I would review that. By default, Rails should not be automatically inserting a new option/select when one is filled out when you have these kinds of nested relationships.

Comment: I cant found any java associated with it

Comment: "the script automatically insert a second select list" which script are taking about?